Approximating an Ellipse with Circular Arcs.
In engineering drawing class, we were required to draw the projection of a cube with a circle inscribed on a face such that each side of the face is tangent to the circle. It is easy to prove that the projection of the face (square) will be a rhombus, and the projection of the circle will be an ellipse. This initially led me to believe that drawing the projection would be very difficult or impossible, but I was surprised to find that method we were taught wasn't.
The rhombus (the projection of the face of the cube) should have an angle of 60 degrees. Here's a method that would work:
In rhombus $ABCD$, where angle $A = 120$ degrees, let $E, F, G$, and $H$ be the midpoints of segments $AB, BC, CD$, and $AD,$ respectively.

Let $I$ be the intersection of segments $AG$ and $CH$.
Draw arc $GH$ with center at $I$.
Let $J$ be the intersection of segments $AF$ and $CE$.
Draw arc $FE$ with center at $J$.
Draw arc $GF$ with center at $A$ and arc $EH$ with center at $C$.


The result should be an ellipse.
However, this appears to be an ellipse, but it is not technically one since an ellipse is not formed by combining finite circular arcs (excluding a circle itself as an ellipse). So, while this method seems correct, it is actually inaccurate.

(The green curve is the only ellipse that passes throw $E,F,G$ and $H$ and is tangent to $AB,BC,CD$ and $AD$  and the red one is the result of applying this method)
As with many things in engineering courses derived from mathematics, this method might be a part of a technique for drawing an ellipse that involves an infinite number of steps. Similar to how some engineering courses omit what they consider unnecessary precision (e.g., taking only the first two or three terms of a Taylor series and neglecting the rest), this method only utilizes four circular arcs.
My questions are: Where does this method originate from, and how can we draw a curve that progressively approaches a true ellipse by incorporating more circular arcs?

Any circular arc has constant curvature, whereas an ellipse has variable curvature throughout. The eye, particularly distracted/obstructed by the other things in that drawing is easily fooled.

A circle inscribed in a square will have four circular arcs that meet at and are tangent to the midpoints of the square. This construction uses four circular arcs that are tangent to the midpoints in a naive fashion.

@CyclotomicField Surly these four arcs are not just random four arcs that tangent to the midpoints they seem to the eye as an ellipse suggesting this could be a part of "echnique for drawing an ellipse that involves an infinite number of steps".

@Mathematicsenjoyer I think it's just a piecewise approximation that accounts for the skewed axes by using the midpoints as references. It's common in technical drawing to use circles to approximate other curves. This one it particularly simple so I'm confident it's pragmatic.

You are looking for polycentric ovals.

Source.
Angelo Mazzotti has literally written the book about them.


There is an infinite family of ellipses that can be inscribed in a rhombus, so the approximate method that is presented in your question only represents one specific possibility for the rhombus with acute interior angle $\pi/3$.
Some computations show that when this rhombus is specified by the vertices $(\pm \sqrt{3}, 0), (0, \pm 1)$, then the unique ellipse that share the same points of tangency as the approximation may be given by the implicit formula
$$\frac{2}{3} x^2 + 2 y^2 = 1. \tag{1}$$  The diagram shows the approximation in red and the true ellipse $(1)$ in blue.  As you can see, the error is noticeable.
If we relax the requirement that the true ellipse must share the same points of tangency, can we get one that fits the approximation better?  Yes.  For instance,
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1, \quad (a,b) = (1.16705, 0.738918)$$
gives the following result:

A question that we could ask is, what is the value of $a$ such that the "error" is minimized?  Another question we could ask is, if we generalize the approximation so that the circles are drawn from points $(\pm h, 0)$ and $(0, \pm k)$, for suitably chosen $h, k$, for what such values is the approximation better than the points chosen for the red curve?

This approximation is of limited use, because it works only if the parallelogram is a rhombus. Try to do that with a generic parallelogram and you'll see that it fails.
In general, if you want to approximate an ellipse with circular arcs, you need two consecutive arcs to have the same tangent at the common endpoint, to give a smooth enough curve. Hence you must partition the ellipse into several pieces with endpoints $EFGH\dots$, find the lines $efgh\dots$ tangent to the ellipse at $EFGH\dots$, and finally construct circular arcs $EF$, $FG$ and so on, tangent to $e$ at $E$, to $f$ at $F$ and so on.
The last construction looks easy, because a line tangent to a circle is perpendicular to the radius issued to the yangency point. Hence you can construct from $E$ the perpendicular $p_E$ to $e$, and from $F$ the perpendicular $p_F$ to $f$: their intersection $J$ must be the center of the circle. But this won't work, in general, because you'll find that $JE\ne JF$ and there is no circle with center $J$ passing through $E$ and $F$.
In your case this works only because your parallelogram is a rhombus and because you chose four tangency points which are symmetric with respect to the diagonals of the rhombus. For instance, $F$ is the reflection of $E$ about diagonal $BD$: that ensures that perpendicular lines $p_E=EC$ and $p_F=AF$ intersect on $BD$, at a point $J$ which is then equidistant from $E$ and $F$.
Unfortunately you cannot improve this construction, even in the case of rhombus. You could think, for instance, of constructing the point $B'$ on the ellipse which is the nearest to $B$ (this is not difficult, even with ruler and compass) and draw the tangent at $B'$ (which is parallel to $EF$) to split arc $EF$ and improve the construction. But, as you can check by yourself, you won't be able to find a circular arc through $EB'$ with the right tangents, for the reasons explained above.

A property of the mechanical-engineering shortcut construction
is that as you change from one arc to the other, the length of the radius changes but the direction of the radius does not.
If you start tracing the curve from midway between $F$ and $G$ in the direction of $G$, The center of curvature is initially at $A$ and the radius is $AG$.
You could imagine the curve as following the end of a taut string of length $AG$ whose other end is affixed at $A$.
But as you pass the point $G$, the string encounters a barrier at point $I$,
and therefore the portion of the string between $A$ and $I$ stops moving. Only the portion of the string beyond $I$ continues to move, and the end of the string now traces a circular arc of radius $IG$.
There is a general form of this kind of construction where instead of simply encountering a barrier at a single point, the string gradually wraps around some shape in the plane as the free end of the string traces a curve.
The shape that the string wraps around is called the evolute of the curve.
You might think of the evolute of a curve as the set of centers of the infinitesimally small circular arcs of which the curve is composed.
The evolute of an ellipse of semimajor axis $a$ and semiminor axis $b$ has the equation
$$ (ax)^{2/3}+(by)^{2/3} =(a^2 - b^2)^{2/3}. $$
If we suppose that $AE=1$ in your figure, the diagonals of the rhombus have lengths
$2$ and $2\sqrt3$. The axes of the ellipse have the same ratio to the diagonals of the rhombus as the diameter the circle has to the diagonals of the square
(since this projection is a linear transformation), that is, they are $\frac1{2\sqrt2}$ times as long.
So the semimajor axis of the ellipse is $a = \sqrt{\frac32}$ and the semiminor axis is
$b = \sqrt{\frac12}.$
The equation of the evolute is then
$$ \left(\frac32 x^2\right)^{1/3} + \left(\frac12 y^2\right)^{1/3} = 1. $$
The graph below shows the projection of the square and the lines that the mechanical-engineering shortcut approximation of the ellipse uses to determine its arcs in black,
the true ellipse in blue, and the evolute of the ellipse in red.

The vertices of the ellipse are the four points where the ellipse crosses its own axes, where the curvature is either maximum or minimum.
As you can see, the centers of curvature for the vertices of the ellipse are much farther from the center of the figure than the four points used as centers of arcs in the mechanical-engineering shortcut.

The description of the evolute as the shape that a string wraps around is a little strange in the case of the ellipse, since the string would have to pass through the inside of the evolute almost all the time while tracing the ellipse. It might be a little easier to suppose that we draw the top half of the ellipse using only the bottom half of the evolute with a string tied at the extreme lower point of that half of the evolute, and draw the bottom half of the ellipse using the mirror image of the top  half's procedure. A more sophisticated idea would be to forget about strings and simply use the formal definition of an evolute.
